# Viewer performance in Internet Explorer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

When looking at a model and turning it in the viewer, the performance is decent in Internet Explorer 11, the problem arises when trying to hide / show nodes. On average computer, on Chrome hiding 79658 nodes takes 5668 milliseconds. On Internet Explorer hiding the same amount of nodes takes 31514 milliseconds. Why is hiding on Internet Explorer so slow? Is there any tricks to make performance better? Are there any updates in future Viewer releases to improve IE performance?

Comment: Unfortunately I dont think there is any simple trick, I guess IE js engine and WebGL pipeline is just slower by nature comparing to Chrome, that's why hiding the nodes is so slow. I also doubt the development team would spend time on optimizing for a browser which is somehow considered deprecated :s

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Philippe comments, there are several reports about this issue, but if you cannot migrate your browser, you may try some suggestions:

- [How to enable or disable software rendering in Internet Explorer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2528233)
- [Improvements to WebGL related performance in Internet Explorer 11](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3118551) [updates]
- [IE 11 WebGL performance slow when using WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25051072/ie-11-webgl-performance-slow-when-using-webbrowser-control) [similar question]